# using onClickView to call another class

Tags: android, button, oncreate

I want to use a button click to pass selection parameters to another class that will build a map screen using the passed parameters. I am focused on getting my button action working. I a using onCLickListener and onCLickView as follows

```
Class1:

public class Class1  extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Class2 class2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

..........

       Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_configup1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);        
   }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        //Save state.. selections and params and use bundle
        //to pass into class2
        class2.execMapBuild();

    }    


}


Class2:
```

public class Class2 extends MapActivity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.drawable.navup);
}


public void execMapBuild() {    
        finish(); //just in case we return.
        Intent intent = new Intent(CLass2.this, Class2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

I have everything working except the desired button action. I want the button click in Class1.onVlickView  to call Class2.execMapBuild using the button click action. I have the button click capturing the action and calling the execMapBuild method on Class2. But I get a NullPointerException as it moves from startActivity(intent) into onCreate.

I have tried several other ways of nailing this down, but this seems the best and I seem close to figuring it out. I would really appreciate an explanation of what I may be missing.
Added code that was initially not copied in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @Heiko Rupp's answer, if you want `Class2` to display a map, it needs to extend something like `Activity`.  As such, you can't just call it with a normal method.  You need to register the `Activity` in your manifest and then call it using an `Intent`.  Here is a sample of the kind of thing you should be doing:

```
public class Class1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_configup1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);        
   }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Class1.this,Class2.class);
        intent.putExtra("key","data");
        ...
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class Class2  extends MapActivity {

    String mData;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mData = extras.getString("key");
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Can I also suggest that you use more descriptive class names than `Class1` and `Class2`.

Comment: Thats my fault in copying code into the window here. Class2 extends MapActivity within my actual code.

Comment: The same principle applies, you can't instantiate it directly by using the `new` keyword, and you can't directly call its methods.  You need to create an `Intent` and call `startActivity()`.

Comment: Actually Class2 Extends MapActivity. I substituted Class1 and Class2 to make it cleaner in the question. I really want to know what would be the best way to do from Class1.onClickView into Class2.execMapBuild. In execMapBuiold I am going to create the data for my ItemizedOverlay. Once done I want to move to onCreate. I hope I am not confusing anyone.

Comment: Look inside my initial code block above. I am using startActivity(intent); there. That is what I first did.

Comment: You can't use the `new` keyword to instantiate an instance of a class that is a sub-class of `Activity`.  It will not work.  Please don't try.  Since you can't create an instance, you can't call your `execMapBuild` method from another class.  You need to use an `Intent` and `Extras` to pass the data from your first `Activity` to your second (as I have done above), then do your data creation in the `onCreate` method of your second `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for you help and explaination, it makes sense. I will give this a try this evening.

Answer (score 2):

`Class2` is no activity, so the callbacks of an Activity will not be called by the system.

And if it were an `Activity`, you could not just call into it via `new Class2()`, as still the callbacks are not executed.

Try to clean this up and then start Class2 activity from Class1 with an `Intent` as you are doing within `execMapBuild()`.

Comment: I will try this. I see your point. I can follow everything into execBuildMap but after startActivity()intent it excepts with a NUllPointerException